# Icecast2 with Let's encrypt

Tags: apache2, icecast, internet-radio

I have an apache webserver on my VPS and Icecast2 on Port 8000.
How can I install SSL on ICECAST 2 without removing my apache webserver?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to install an ACME client?  How to generate a certificate with one?  How to concatenate your certificate together?  How to edit the Icecast config?  How to configure Icecast to listen on a particular port?  Please break it down to a specific question.

Comment: Okay, sorry - I want to know how can I configure Icecast on Port 8000 with SSL - I have read that I have to change something in my apache config because Icecast should be on the domain which contains the certs, so when I call my domain ice.example.com , it have to show my icecast - Is it right or is it possible without changing something in the apache config?

Comment: I don't follow what Apache has to do with it.  Icecast is its own server, independent of Apache.  If you are using the same certificate for Apache and Icecast (such as in the case of the same hostname, or with a wildcard cert), then you still have to copy the files in both places because Icecast uses a format where the certificate and key are concatenated together.

Comment: Okay, but how can I generate than a certificate without configuring my Apache Server? My domain ice.example.com redirects to my webserver and ice.example.com:8000 redirects to Icecast - When I create a cert with certonly, I get the error "Invalid response from ice.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/...."

Comment: You can either set up a static folder in your Icecast config and set your ACME client to output to it, or you can use the DNS challenge method.  You can also use the built-in server of the ACME client, but that won't work for renewals if the real server is running.

Comment: How can I exactly do this? Like this: certbot certonly --webroot-path="/usr/share/icecast2/web" -d ice.example.com ? After I have put the privkey and cert to one .pem together, I get the following error: connection/get_ssl_certificate No SSL capability

Comment: Sounds like the build you have of Icecast wasn't compiled with SSL.  Use the official builds.

Comment: I've tried it with the official package (apt install icecast2) and the version 2.4.4.-1 from XIPH - On both versions I get the same error